# How to test Aeotec home energy monitor

Tags: smart-home, samsung-smartthings

I recently got a Aeotec home energy monitor (v1 or v2, I'm not sure) (HEM) to pair with Smartthings via Z-Wave. I would like to test it out before I make the effort to add a weatherized electrical outlet near my breaker and actually connect the clamps to the electrical lines.

What have I done so far?

So far, I've added a device handler from the Smartthings IDE and added HEM as a device. I don't think the paring even worked correctly as this is the first time I'm adding a custom device handler in Smartthings. It seems to be non-functional as I can't see any variations when I connected the HEM to my electrical dryer's power line.

So my question is, how do I test the functionality of HEM without actually connecting to electrical lines?